# Can you deactivate parameters without deleting them in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have put parameters in my report. I have commented them out in my dataset but I found that when I preview the report, the parameters are still active. How can I deactivate the parameter without deleting them from the parameters section?

Answer (score 1):

Go into the properties of your parameter. There is a Visibility setting there. You can set it to Hidden or Internal. Either of these will make it invisible when you run the report. You will need to specify a Default Value, but the value won't matter since it's not being applied to anything.